# Custom pages redirect error of non www to www of wordpress site developed from microsoft azure

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, redirect, web-config

I have added this code in `web.config` of my wordpress site:

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW site">
  <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This perfectly works for redirection like homepage, default wordpress url(login.php, wp-admin). Examples:

1. If I go to link poudelmadhav.com it redirects to www.poudelmadhav.com
2. If I go to link poudelmadhav.com/wp-login.php it redirects to www.poudelmadhav.com/wp-login.php

But this doesnot work in custom pages of wordpress that I have created after installing wordpress. For examples:

1. If I want to go poudelmadhav.com/contact it redirects to www.poudelmadhav.com not www.poudelmadhav.com/contact
2. If I want to go poudelmadhav.com/about-me it redirects to www.poudelmadhav.com not www.poudelmadhav.com/about-me

I have followed the instructions from [here.](https://www.surinderbhomra.com/Blog/Post/2015/01/18/Redirect-Non-WWW-to-WWW-Domain-In-Azure-Websites)
How can I solve this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue on my site. To fix this, you'll need to move the code you posted above before `Rewrite to index.php` rule in the `web.config` file as below. And don't forget to clear the web browser's cache when you test it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>

                <rule name="Redirect to WWW site">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aron . My problem solved. You are my great inspirations...